# making horizontal bar graph scrollable chartjs and angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, ng2-charts

I have a chart that displays a good number of data and i would like to make it scrollable so that graph bars are displayed comfortably - The xaxis will remain in position as i would scroll down in the graph to see more data.

Here is a plunker of what i have so far: https://plnkr.co/edit/u9n9VztN7Xb1vkfedthv?p=preview

```
<div style="width:100%; display:block">
      <canvas *ngIf="loaded" baseChart [data]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChartType" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
      </canvas>
    </div>

getData(){
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data => {
      this.resultData = data;
      this.barChartLabels = this.resultData.map(item => item.label);
      this.barChartData = this.resultData.map(item => item.data);
      this.loaded = true;
    }
  }
```

how can i adjust this so it will display about 5 bars and then scroll down to the remaining bar?